# Can we use SXA Search Functionality with JSS pages

Tags: sxa, jss

With Sitecore 9.2 and JSS, can we use the SXA search functionality and configuration (scopes and boosting etc.) with JSS ?

Has anyone done this or did you encounter any specific issues?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. The whole logic (scopes, boosting, ...) can be used only by SXA search renderings at the moment.